# Error while querying the partitioned table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have created a partition table and trying to query the partition but not able to do so in sql server 2016. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [financialStatementPartition](datetime) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2013-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2014-01-01T00:00:00.000', 
                           N'2015-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-01-01T00:00:00.000', 
                           N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000')
GO
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds]
(
    [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
    [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
    [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
    [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
    [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
    [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
)
```

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.FinancialStatementIds
WHERE $PARTITION.financialStatementPartition(periodenddate) = '2013-01-01T00:00:00.000'
```

Error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2013-01-01T00:00:00.000' to data type int.

Comment: What is $PARTITITION ?

Comment: Its a new inbuilt function to query partioned tables

Comment: The reason for the error message is most certainly the fact, that `$PARTITION` returns a partiton number - and '2013-01-01T00:00:00.000' is not a number, right? ;-) Try `SELECT $PARTITION.financialStatementPartition('2013-01-01T00:00:00.000')`instead

Comment: doesnt work. get error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.FinancialStatementIds
WHERE periodenddate = '20130101'
```

Anyway, the table is still not partitioned properly. You need to apply Partition Scheme to connect the table and Partition function.

Comment: partition scheme is already in place. Had missed putting in the post

Comment: Hi kamil, how sure are we that this query is querying the data from the partition. Do you know any other way of doing that ?